# Customize Share Intent Android

Tags: android, share, android-gallery

i want to share images from gallery to my App i am using the following code to do that but i am not able to see myApp in Share option. i am using Android mobile version - 4.0.3

**Mcode:**

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m.media"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i want my App to be in the Share options please tell me where i am going wrong and suggest me the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be because you are only registering for the MULTIPLE intent.

try adding this intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```